# Why Dakshina is given to Guru?

Tags: scripture, practice, culture, customs

In ancient Gurukula System after the education, the students are required to give Guru Dakshina to their respective Guru. Why is this practice when we have stayed with the master and served him all through the childhood? And why does the Guru demands for a particular thing as Dakshina ?

Comment: Why do you pay fees in school and college?

Comment: To pay off debt of Vidya

Comment: I don't think the ancient education system believed in selling the Vidya just like our modern school and college. The ancient learning center was Temple of Sarasvati not Temple of Lakshmi. And the education imparted to the pupil by the Guru is beyond the measure of any wealth .

Comment: @moonstar2001 Really? Schools and colleges? Guru is meant for Spiritual guru. The teacher in schools and colleges are not Guru, they are mere teachers or Shikshakas. They are no more than any normal human being. I amuse when in schools those mere human being teachers start thinking themselves as God on the basis of- "Guru Govind Dou khade..." and "GururBrahma GururVishnurGururDevo Maheshwara..."

Comment: @AnuragSingh loukika vidya is also important and people did learn the arts and the sciences in gurukulas. They offered dakshinas to their gurus. It is said a person who teaches us even one letter is to be revered. Remember Dattatreya considered even quadrupeds as gurus. But yes, atma vidya guru is the most superior of all.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Yes it is true that each thing is also a Guru if it gives a single teaching. The statement that Guru is Brahma is verily for Atma Vidya Guru.

Answer (score 7):

The Manu Smriti declares:

> Manu Smriti 12.83. Studying the Veda, (practising) austerities, (the acquisition of true) knowledge, the subjugation of the organs, abstention from
>   doing injury, **and serving the Guru** are the **best means for attaining
>   supreme bliss.**

And,this service to Guru is **four-fold** as told in the Kularnava Tantra(KT):

> Service to the Guru is fourfold: **service by self, service by means**,
>   service by honouring, service by happy feeling(KT)

In Hinduism the Guru is equated with the supreme Para Brahman:

> **Verily, the Guru is none else but Sadashiva; that is the truth, there is no doubt about it**.Shiva himself is the Guru; otherwise who
>   is it that gives fulfilment and liberation?(KT)

The symbolic meaning of a **Sisya**(disciple)is also given in the Kularnava Tantra as follows:

> Sisya: He who dedicates **his body, wealth**, the pranas to the holy Gurus
>   and learns, Siksate, yoga from the Gurus, is called sisya(KT).

So, a Sisya can repay his debts to his Guru by **his body and wealth** but what is this debt all about?How big that debt actually is?

The Shastras say that the ultimate goal of each being is the the state of Moksha or liberation and also that it can **only** be achieved by the grace of a Guru :

> Neither asramas (prescribed stages in life) nor philosophies nor
>   sciences can give the deliverance; only Jnana can give it. **And this
>   Jnana is received through the Word of the Guru.** All other ways are
>   deceptive, oppressive; the Truth-Knowledge alone is life-giving(KT).

And,

> The Sruti declares that for those who seek for fulfilment and
>   liberation, who aspire to attain to Brahma, Vishnu and Isha, **devotion
>   to the Guru is the Path and no other**
>
> **There is no truth higher than the Guru**, no Godhead greater than Shiva,
>   no Science greater than the Veda, no Philosophy equal to the Kaula, no
>   Knowledge greater than the Kula, no happiness greater than Jnana, no
>   worship greater than the Puja of eight limbs, **no fruit greater than
>   Mukti.**

And a Guru can only grant Mukti.So,the debt that a Sisya owes to his Guru is indeed very great.**That is why he needs to repay the debt by paying Guru Dakshina.**

But even ,here,devotion is what actually that matters:

> **Even if you give the whole of your wealth to the Guru
>   but without devotion, then the fruit will not accrue to you.** For
>   indeed devotion is the only cause.

And,btw, a "Dakshina" is also offered to a Deity while offering Puja by saying "Dakshinam samarpayami" because,in general,the Shastras say that Gods,Gurus are never to be visited  empty handed:

> Do not approach royalty, the Deity and the Guru empty-handed. Offer in
>   the measure of your capacity, fruit, flower, cloth and the like(KT)

So,these are,in short,the reasons why we offer a Guru Dakshina.

Comment: a well-written answer to the question. But I have some doubt,that why should a Guru be offered with the wealth when he doesn't need and Why does the guru demand for a particular thing as Dakshina ?

Comment: @Ganesh Thanks.Actually Shastras tell us that Guru and the Supreme Brahman are one and the same.One should not differentiate btween the two,so just like we are to offer the foods before eating to God(although he does not actually need that food) similarly here **"Whatever objects of enjoyment there be,
offer them first to the Guru and take to them as
his leavings**..although as u can see from  the answer  that service to Guru can be done through ur body and wealth etc..but i am not sure if asking for extreme dakshina like in the case of Ekalavya is Dharmic or not.

Comment: @UdayKrishna Yes that is also true.

Comment: @ Rickross Usually, I have noticed in the case of Ekalavya and Krishna where the Guru have demanded their Dakshina. Is it always that a Guru demands his Dakshina and is it random.

Comment: @ganesh  Shirdi sai  an avatar of Lord siva demanded Dakshina and spent [gave alms] within that day itself. It is said is sai satcharitra why he demanded dakshina is to drive off the sins we committed in the past births which we do not know but he knows as he is antaryaami.

Comment: @Ganesh It is not always so the case,but it is within the rights of a Guru to demand a dakshina, that is legitimate, from his disciple ,after the completion of the course.Anyways,finding Gurus like the way they are mentioned/described in Scriptures, in Kali Yuga, is very difficult

Comment: @Ganesh--Kindly read sai satcharitra if you have time. You will come to know the sadguru sai.

Comment: "Whatever objects of enjoyment there be, offer them first to the Guru and take to them as his leavings" And what if disciple doesn't have anything to give?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria If he has nothing what will he offer???That was said with an assumption..btw did u not read the other quote which talks about devotion?..being devoted to Guru is what actually matters..

Comment: @Rickross Yes that is what I actually wanted to say, I believe complete devotion is more than enough for guru.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why is dakṣiṇā given to a Guru?

Because it's usually a brāhmaṇa who can become a guru and he has no other source of income, he has to subsist on dakṣiṇā to lead a healthy lifestyle and to continue imparting knowledge to future disciples who may not afford to pay him a dakṣiṇā after graduating.

#### Why practice this when we've stayed with the master and served him all through our childhood?

Serve him how? Fetch him water? Wash his clothes? What about food? Maybe he has some cows and agricultural land, so you serve him by milking the cow and tilling his land. But what if one of his cows dies, doesn't he need more cows to sustain? There can be no rain and the land becomes barren. Think on those lines.

#### And why does the Guru *demand* a particular thing as dakṣiṇā?

He shouldn't. A guru who *demands* dakṣiṇā is not a proper guru. "He is permitted to receive a dakṣiṇā to maintain himself", says, [Swami Chandrasekarendra Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati) in the book *[Hindu Dharma: The Universal Way of Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8172760558)* <sup>§</sup>

> The Brahmin must be conversant with the fourteen branches of the Vedic lore. He must be proficient even in Gandharva-veda or music and must be acquainted with agricultural science, construction of houses, etc. At the same time he must give instructions in these subjects to pupils from the appropriate castes. His own vocation is the study of the Vedas and **he must have no other source of income.**
>
> Visvamitra was the master of Dhanurveda (military science). When he performed sacrifices, the demons Subahu and Marica tried to play havoc with them. **Though a great warrior himself he did not try to drive away the demons himself. Instead, he brought Rama and Laksmana for the purpose.** Visvamitra thereafter gave the instruction to the two in the use of astras and sastras.
>
> If the Brahmin is asked, "Do you know to wield a knife? " he must be able to answer, "Yes, I know". If he is asked, "Do you know to draw and paint" again he must say, "Yes". But he cannot wield a knife or become an artist to earn his livelihood. All he can do is to learn these arts and teach others the same according to their caste. He is permitted to receive a daksina to maintain himself and **he must be contented with it however small the sum may be**. The Brahmin's speciality, his true vocation, is Vedic learning.
>
> [ Hindu Dharma » Varna Dharma For Universal Well-Being » Brahmins are not a Privileged Caste ]

<sup>§</sup>  <sub>An older and copyright-free version of this book is available for free [here](http://www.kamakoti.org/newlayout/template/hindudharma.html).</sub>